# How to rotate a point in 3d?

Tags: matrices, 3d, rotations

I am trying to rotate a point in 3d space. I have a point `p` and a xrotation `rx`, yrotation `yr` and a zrotation `zr`.

How can I use this arbitrary rotation function

[image]

To get the rotated point `p'` which has the new x,y,z values.

Can anyone explain?

Thanks

Comment: Treat point as a vector $p$. You can use your formula $p_r=Rp$.

Comment: but I have 3 rotation values, yet $R$ just uses 1 theta variable. How do I get theta?

Comment: And is $p = (u_x, u_y, u_z)$ in my case?

Comment: If you have 3 rotations compose them $R=R_1 R_2 R_3$. You don't have to find $\theta$.

Comment: Isn't the point of this arbitrary rotation matrix to do all 3 rotations in 1 matrix calculation?

Comment: this matrix is a rotation matrix for axis-angle representation.. you can use it if you have axis and angle,  see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Rotation_matrix_from_axis_and_angle